# Retrieving data from OPC-Server

Tags: python-2.7, opc

The connection is made to the server OPC ( Local Area Network ) via `OpenOPC`.

The problem is that after a few requests for data , they cease to act and the error takes off on `timeout`. Increasing the `timeout` does not work

Who faced, how to fight it?

(DCOM is not configurable and is not being considered, but if you do not dare, to have to organize connection via DCOM)

Comment: Very open question.

First check your firewall settings on server and client computer.

Have you searched on the openopc site for known issues and questions? There are a lot regarding this topic. But you need to give more information that just time out. What are you doing precisely?

Comment: @Studeerkamertechnicus.
Yes I searched, but found nothing. The problem manifests itself even if used on a server that is running the OPC- server - hence the problem is not in the network settings.

Comment: A proper firewall also blocks internal traffic.
Disable it.
Whenever you're unable to read from a local server, it most of the time a DCOM issue.
If you take Matrikon's OPC explorer, or a different certified(!) opc client, does it see the OPC server at all on the local machine?
Try also their analyzer.
https://www.matrikonopc.com/products/opc-desktop-tools/opc-analyzer.aspx

Comment: @Studeerkamertechnicus. 
Yes , Matrikon OPC explorer sees the data server.
The connection is not via DCOM.
The server connection is successfully made​​. The data is not returned. Firewall and antivirus disabled.

Comment: Are you using OPC UA or OPC Classic (DA etc) ?

Comment: @Studeerkamertechnicus.
OPC DA 2.05a & OPC HDA 1.20

Comment: @ivanK. were you able to solve this issue? If yes could you share how you were able to connect to the OPC DA without using DCOM, i'm stuck in a similar problem. thanks!

Comment: @Nachiketh. Connecting I carried out, but it was unstable, to connect using python + OpenOPC (Library)

Comment: @ivanK. is there a better/alternate way of doing this? Please let me know. Thanks!